# Spring Boot não inicia no modo Debug (Java)

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com SpringBoot e não consigo iniciar minha aplicação apenas em modo **debug**. (Se não for debug ele inicia normalmente)
Parece que entra em loop e essa mensagem de erro fica aparecendo no log

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getClassLoaderFor(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1444) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getClassLoaderFor(JmxMBeanServer.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$6.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1365) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getClassLoaderFor(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1362) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:813) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
```

Alguem pode me ajudar ?
Obrigado!!

**EDIT**

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableHystrix
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "..."}) 
@ComponentScan({"..."})
public class UploadApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UploadApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Bota ai a classe com a config do `SpringBoot`.

Comment: Tenho varias classes de configuracao (mongodb, oauth2, restcontext, etc)  não vai dar pra colocar todas aqui, posso colocar a classe principal, não sei se ajuda

Comment: Um erro comum é que aplicação possui muitos breakpoints..tente remover todos eles e iniciar novamente em modo debug. Para remover todos, se estive no eclipse, vá em Window > Show View > Other > Pesquise por breakpoints. Lá você vai encontrar um X para remover todos.

Comment: @LucasCosta Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso, tinha 15 breakpoints, tirei como vc sugeriu e funcionou !!, coloca na resposta pra voce ganhar os pontos =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um erro comum é que aplicação possui muitos breakpoints..tente remover todos eles e iniciar novamente em modo debug. Para remover todos, se estive no *eclipse*, faça o seguinte:

`Window > Show View > Other`

Pesquise por breakpoints. Lá você vai encontrar um X para remover todos.